# Mysql permission structure

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, user-permissions

I am having a hard time understanding MySQL 5.1 permission level.
So I have this user USERA, which has, according to my hosting control panel, have access to all features of a database ( manage stored procedures, functions, views and triggers ).

When I use phpmyadmin ( or other software ), my user is not allowed to do so.
After a while, I ended up giving my user SUPER, so that the DB manager, could allow me to make those things.

What I don't understand is, when I give ALL privs to my database ( specific privs to the DB ), I still don't get to the features I need.

But if I define ALL privs to my DB at a global level, ( incld. SUPER ) I get to see all DB's from the system.

What boggles my mind is why on earth does mysql doesn't allow me privs when I have set my user to specific database? I can see that they are set, but when I go to make some routines, they are not available to me...

Thank you for any help provided.
Regards

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version do you have?

Comment: 4.0.10.4 with Mysql 5.1